# Quantifiers in the definition of uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, definition, uniform-convergence

Am I right to write the definition of uniform convergence as follows?

$(f_n)$ converges to $f$ uniformly if and only if 
$$\forall\epsilon>0, \exists N\in\mathbb{N}, \forall n, \forall x (n\geq N  \Rightarrow |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon) $$

I am not sure where should I put $\forall x$.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: Note that "$\forall n\ \forall x$" is the same as "$\forall x\ \forall n$", but the "$\exists N$" must be before both of them.

Answer (score 5):

The uniform convergence means that starting from a certain $N$, all $f_n$ functions are included in a "band"(yellow one bellow), they are approaching the limit function $f$ uniformly, *i.e*, the functions $f_n$ are approaching the limit globally. Therefore, starting from $N$ all the values of the function $f_n$ for a certain $n$ are in the band. That is what you said : $ \forall n\geq N, \forall x : |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ .

[image: Uniform convergence]

Comment: Thanks. By the way, how you draw the picture?